# How to pass a variable from one javascript file to another helpers.js file

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm trying to pass a css selector from one javascript file to another helpers.js file, specifically in a casper.js script.

My script.js file is...

```
var titleSelector = {
    value: '[itemprop="title"]'
};


var processPage = function () {

    this.wait(2000, function () {

    titles = this.evaluate(helpers.getTitles);
    utils.dump(titles);
```

My helpers.js file is

```
var helpers = {
    getTitles: function () {
        var tt = document.querySelectorAll(titleSelector.value);
        return [].map.call(tt, function (t) {
            return t.innerText;
        });

    }
}
```

If i hardcode '[itemprop="title"]' in place of titleSelector.value in the helpers.js file the function works, but I can't figure out how to pass it from script.js.

Can anybody advise how I can achieve this.  Any help appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your `var titleSelector` inside any function or is it in the root of the file

Comment: It is in the root of the file @NadirLaskar

Comment: Then there should be no problem accessing the variable

Comment: make sure your `helper.js` is loaded after  `script.js`
also share your error log from console what are you getting in the console

Comment: I'm just running script.js from the console and script.js is injecting helper.js.  Other functions in the helpers file are working and if selector is hardcoded in to the function it works.

Answer (score 2):

Add a parameter to getTitles so you can pass in the selector, then [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the variable (titleSelector) as the first argument to the function. This is the more old-school solution.

```
// in script.js
titles = this.evaluate(helpers.getTitles.bind(null, titleSelector));

// in helper.js
var helpers = {
    getTitles: function (titleSelector) {
        var tt = document.querySelectorAll(titleSelector.value);
        return [].map.call(tt, function (t) {
            return t.innerText;
        });
    }
}
```

Another way to do it is to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the getTitles function so it gets a parameter and returns a function to do the actual work. Function.prototype.bind() is essentially doing this for us in the above example.

```
// in script.js
titles = this.evaluate(helpers.getTitles(titleSelector));

// in helper.js
var helpers = {
    getTitles: function (titleSelector) { return function() {
        var tt = document.querySelectorAll(titleSelector.value);
        return [].map.call(tt, function (t) {
            return t.innerText;
        });
    }}
}
```

Here's a slightly modified working example using currying:

```html
<div itemprop="title">MY TITLE</div>
<div itemprop="title">ANOTHER TITLE</div>


<script>
  var helpers = {
    getTitles: ts => () => {
      var tt = document.querySelectorAll(ts.value);
      return [].map.call(tt, function(t) {
        return t.innerText;
      });

    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  var titleSelector = {
    value: '[itemprop="title"]'
  };

  // Mocking utils
  const utils = {
    dump: x => console.log("DUMP", x)
  }


  const container = {
    wait: (_, cb) => cb(), // Pretend to sleep
    evaluate: cb => cb(), // Evaluates the cb
    processPage: function() {
      this.wait(2000, () => {
        titles = this.evaluate(helpers.getTitles(titleSelector));
        utils.dump(titles);
      })
    }
  }

  container.processPage()
</script>
```

Comment: Neither of the above seem to be working for me.  Would I need to add any further requires or anything @James Kraus

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console? I need something to work off of.

Comment: No, it's just returning null instead of dumping the values.

Comment: Strange thing is, i added  selector: function(titleSelector){ var s = titleSelector.value; return s; } to the var helpers. Then console.log(helpers.selector(titleSelector)); from script.js and it's returning [itemprop="title"]. So, really don't understand why getTitles isn't working. Tried changing to this.selector as well and still returning null instead of the array of titles???

Comment: Updated my answer with a working example. Based on what I've got, this looks like you might have another issue outside of the code you posted.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I'm not at computer anymore, but will try this tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Thank you